# Can we say "help yourself" considering that you're ready to share your food

Tags: word-choice, grammar

For example:

Do you want some cookies?
no
Are you sure?
Yes
If you'll change your mind. Help yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not very clear, but I would think:

> *Help yourself if you change your mind*.

perfectly adequate.